# $reduce with $regex in $group aggregation so that length can be displayed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I think I have a pretty complex one here - not sure if I can do this or not.

I have data that has an address and a data field. The data field is a hex value. I would like to run an aggregation that groups the data by address and then the length of the hex data. All of the data will come in as 16 characters long, but the length of that data should calculated in bytes.

I think I have to take the data, strip the trailing 00's (using regex 00+$), and divide that number by 2 to get the length. After that, I would have to then group by address and final byte length.

An example dataset would be:

```
{addr:829, data:'4100004822000000'}
{addr:829, data:'4100004813000000'}
{addr:829, data:'4100004804000000'}
{addr:506, data:'0000108000000005'}
{addr:506, data:'0000108000000032'}
{addr:229, data:'0065005500000000'}
```

And my desired output would be:

```
{addr:829, length:5}
{addr:506, length:8}
{addr:229, length:4}
```

Is this even possible in an aggregation query w/o having to use external code to do?

Comment: is data field actually a string data type?  or Binary type?  if it's string, it's definitely possible.  if binary then likely not.

Answer (score 3):

This is not too complicated if your "data" is in fact strings as you show in your sample data.   Assuming data exists and is set to something (you can add error checking as needed) you can get the result you want like this:

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {$addFields:{lastNonZero:{$add:[2,{$reduce:{
        initialValue:-2,
        input:{$range:[0,{$strLenCP:"$data"},2]},
        in:{$cond:{
            if: {$eq:["00",{$substr:["$data","$$this",2]}]},
            then: "$$value",
            else: "$$this"
        }}
    }}]}}},
    {$group:{_id:{
        addr:"$addr", 
        length:{$divide:["$lastNonZero",2]}
    }}}
])
```

I used two stages but of course they could be combined into a single `$group` if you wish.  Here in `$reduce` I step through `data` 2 characters at a time, checking if they are equal to `"00"`.  Every time they are not I update the value to where I am in the sequence.  Since that returns the position of the last non-"00" characters, we add 2 to it to find where the string of zeros that goes to the end starts and then later in $group we divide that by 2 to get the true length.

On your sample data, this returns:

```
{ "_id" : { "addr" : 229, "length" : 4 } }
{ "_id" : { "addr" : 506, "length" : 8 } }
{ "_id" : { "addr" : 829, "length" : 5 } }
```

You can add a `$project` stage to transform the field names into ones you want returned.

Comment: I think this is close, but I believe I need to use the regex to remove the trailing 00's. If the data field being calculated equals 0080310000000000, then this routine comes back with a length of 1.5 instead of the expected 3. 00 is the first byte, 80 is the second, and 31 is the third. Also, if you use a data string like 0000032f00000015, I'd expect that to be a length of 8 and this method calculates a length of 4.

Comment: no, it doesn't.  Try it.  It returns 3 for the first one and 8 for the second one.  Where did you get 1.5 and 4 from?